# How to use ffmpeg to concat mpeg4-aac mp4s?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I know that you can concat h264-aac mp4s using the following command:

ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb OUTPUT.ts

(as per http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#Bitstream-Filters)

and it says there that modified bsf options could be used to concat mpeg4 files, but does not say what it is (without bsf transcode would fail).

Anyone know what options to use here?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4) MPEG-4, which *parts* of the spec were you using when you originally encoded the data? A common option would be "Part 2" (Advanced Simple Profile). I don't think there is an ASP concatenation bitstream filter. Try it without one. If it fails, I don't think any of the remaining BSFs will get the job done.

Comment: Yea, I'm talking about Part 2. No bsf does not work. Guess I may have to re-encode it...it sounds like there is a way to do it without re-encoding though.

Comment: The term "concat" generally refers to joining files with the `concat` [demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1), [protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat), or [filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). I don't really understand what you're asking, but I believe you just want to re-mux to another container format, right?

Comment: I want to simply concat multiple videos in serial order. e.g. for h264-acc, you just make each individual video into mpegts format and then using the concat file protocol to concat them together. this very same method does not work for mpeg4 (simple format)-aac videos.

Comment: Don't know, but you might have better luck with [Gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gnonlin/html/GnlComposition.html) -- [here is an example](https://gist.github.com/gipi/1402097)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! **Use the bsf called "mpeg4_unpack_bframes".** This bsf has an unintuitive name, but it allows you to use "mpeg4" video to write directly to .ts and then immediately to concatenated .mp4.

Here's the script that I'm using in a batch file now to do so:

```
ffmpeg -i "input_1.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i "input_2.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes -f mpegts intermediate2.ts

ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "input_[FULL].mp4"
```